# ECG compliant alternative method for file_get_contents (remote XML)

Tags: magento-1, xml, coding-standards, magento-ecg

What is correct "ECG-way" to load an remote XML file?

For local files this works:

```
$xml = new Varien_Simplexml_Config($configFile);
$node = $xml->getNode('my/selected/node');
```

But not from remote URL:

> Varien_Simplexml_Config

```
public function __construct($sourceData=null) {
    if (is_null($sourceData)) {
        return;
    }
    if ($sourceData instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
       $this->setXml($sourceData);
    } elseif (is_string($sourceData) && !empty($sourceData)) {
        if (strlen($sourceData)<1000 && is_readable($sourceData)) {
            $this->loadFile($sourceData);
        } else {
            $this->loadString($sourceData);
        }
    }
    #$this->setCache(new Varien_Simplexml_Config_Cache_File());
    #$this->getCache()->setConfig($this);
}
```

Because `$sourceData` isn't readable it tries to load a XML string, what also doesn't work, because it's just the remote URL ...

**Question:** is there a method in `Varien` or `Zend` library that is usable for loading remote XML files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl` but it's just a fancy way of doing a `curl`.

Comment: A workaround for a workaround? :) Seems to be a bit too much overhead, so i'll stay with `file_get_contents()` if there is nothing equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to use `Varien_Io_File` and the `read` method:

```
public function read($filename, $dest=null)
{
    if (!is_null($dest)) {
        chdir($this->_cwd);
        $result = @copy($filename, $dest);
        chdir($this->_iwd);
        return $result;
    }

    chdir($this->_cwd);
    $result = @file_get_contents($filename);
    chdir($this->_iwd);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: isn't this destined for local files?

Comment: @Marius with `file_get_contents` you can get whatever file you want

Comment: I know I know...But I was wondering about it's moral :)

Comment: @Marius it's used in `Mage_Paypal_Model_Report_Settlement` in the `fectchAndSave` method to go to a specified host/path and fetch a report from there so I guess we're good ^^

Comment: I get the XML string, but with a PHP warning `Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)`. Just to note `Mage_Paypal_Model_Report_Settlement` uses `Varien_Io_Sftp` ...

Comment: @sv3n it's because the method expect a destination directly as the second parameter

Comment: With 2nd parameter set it would copy the file ... or do is miss something?

Comment: @sv3n yes my bad sorry